# Application.Transpose 2D array assigment

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

For example I have 2d array

```
tKey(0, 0) = 1
tKey(1, 0) = 2
tKey(2, 0) = 3
```

So

```
testArray = Application.Transpose(tKey)
```

assign like 1D array

```
testArray(1) = 1
testArray(2) = 2
testArray(3) = 3
```

Instead of expected

```
testArray(1,1) = 1
testArray(1,2) = 2
testArray(1,3) = 3
```

But if tKey

```
tKey(0, 0) = 1
tKey(1, 0) = 2
tKey(2, 0) = 3
tKey(0, 1) = 1
tKey(1, 1) = 2
tKey(2, 1) = 3
```

then

```
testArray = Application.Transpose(tKey)
```

assign like 2D array, like expected

```
testArray(1,1) = 1
testArray(1,2) = 2
testArray(1,3) = 3
testArray(2,1) = 1
testArray(2,2) = 2
testArray(2,3) = 3
```

test code

```
Sub testss()
    Dim tKey(0 To 2, 0 To 0) As Variant
        tKey(0, 0) = 1
        tKey(1, 0) = 2
        tKey(2, 0) = 3
            testArray1 = Application.Transpose(tKey) ' wrong assignment
    Dim tKey2(0 To 2, 0 To 1) As Variant
        tKey2(0, 0) = 1
        tKey2(1, 0) = 2
        tKey2(2, 0) = 3
        tKey2(0, 1) = 1
        tKey2(1, 1) = 2
        tKey2(2, 1) = 3
            testArray2 = Application.Transpose(tKey2) ' good assignment
    Stop
End Sub
```

Is that a bug? How to assign correct one value to 2d array using Application.Transpose?

Comment: In your 2D into a 1D what doesn't that make sense to you?  Basically Array1(Row, Column) becomes Array2(Column, Row) since you have only one column a the start of your example col 0, in your transpose you will have only one row (row 0), but you are losing me along the way in some of your examples it appears you are mixing both zero based arrays and 1 based arrays, I think the compiler realizes you dont have a 2D array in that assignment as the transposed array is a single row with multiple elements (cols), this part in particular doesn't feel right: testArray(1,1) = 1
....
testArray(2,3) = 3

Comment: I need loop 2d array, sometimes it has only one column but i need hold it in 2d array